How to set startDestination in Jetpack compose navigation
@Composable
fun RootNav() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val authViewModel: AuthViewModel = hiltViewModel()

    val authState by authViewModel.authState.collectAsState()
    val startDestination = when (authState) {
        is AuthState.Unauthenticated -> ScreenRoutes.AuthNav.route
        is AuthState.AuthenticatedWithoutCouple -> ScreenRoutes.RegisterNav.route
        is AuthState.AuthenticatedWithCouple -> ScreenRoutes.HomeNav.route
        else -> ScreenRoutes.AuthNav.route
    }
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = startDestination
    ) {
        AuthNav(authViewModel, navController)

        RegisterNav(navController)

        composable(route = ScreenRoutes.HomeNav.route) {
            HomeNavGraph(navController){
                authViewModel.signOut()
            }
        }
    }
}

I have a structure like the one below, it works correctly but the user always sees the Login screen, how can I fix this?

add this in your startDestination code.
else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Route $authState is not recognised ")

You collected authState from AuthViewModel so I guest that your authState is initially set to AuthState.Unauthenticated in your AuthViewModel, something like:
val authState: MutableStateFlow<AuthState>(AuthState.Unauthenticated)

so your startDestination is always AuthState.Unauthenticated first before it's updated to any other value

Well, can I decide on this on the splash screen and direct it? If so, how can I do it?

Of course, you can do it in splash screen. Just create a custom splash screen then implement your logic ^^

About custom splash screen, you can think of it as a normal activity. Set launcher intent-filter to it in AndroidManifest.xml then implement your navigate logic

Thanks for your help, this is how I solved the problem
Solution Gist link

Glad to hear you solved it ^^

startDestination defines which destination should be displayed when NavHost is first executed. So it will always be what authState is initially set to. Most likely your view model sets the initial value of the authState flow to AuthState.Unauthenticated.
Whatever the flow's value later may be set to doesn't matter because the NavHost won't change the destination on recompostion. It already has a startDestination which it displays, if you want to navigate to somewhere else you need to use navController.navigate().
Long story short: Make sure authState already contains the correct value on first composition.
You can always decide to stick with the flow, but then you would need to display something else instead of the NavHost until the desired authState is available. This could be achieved by setting the initialValue of the StateFlow to null and display a loading screen until that changes to an AuthState.
